# How to use the LINQ where expression?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm implementing the service \ repository pattern in a new project.  I've got a base interface that looks like this. Everything works great until I need to use the GetMany method.  I'm just not sure how to pass a LINQ expression into the GetMany method.  For example how would I simply sort a list of objects of type name?

nameRepository.GetMany( ? )

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T GetById(long Id);
    T GetById(string Id);
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);

}



 public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
 {
    return dbset.Where(where).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: Note that you can use generics like : GetById(U id) , instead of getting string or long .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you had an implementation of `IRepository<MyClass>`, you would make a call to `GetMany` like so:

```
IRepository<MyClass> repository = ...;

IEnumerable<MyClass> filtered = repository.GetMany(
    mc => true);
```

Note the `mc => true` [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  `mc` in this case is the parameter (in this case, of type `MyClass`) passed to the `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` which will be evaluated (one would assume through an [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx)) and the `mc.SomeProperty == someValue` is an expression which returns `true`, which is the second type parameter of the `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

Once you have the `filtered`, you can use the [`order by`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx) clause (or the [`OrderBy` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), they're the same) to sort the results, like so:

```
var filteredAndOrdered = filtered.OrderBy(mc => mc.MyProperty);
```

Note that `GetMany` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, *not* an `IQueryable<T>`; this is important if your result set is large, as the ordering will happen on the client, and not be sent to the server.

For an `OrderBy` operation, this can be expensive because it has to go through the entire sequence (to order) before returning the first result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The example provided is with a condition, I'm simply looking for a way to return all object sorted using the get many.

Comment: Thanks, it was the mc => true part that was throwing me off.